# Calculating difference between two time fields and storing it in Django model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model that contains time fields for a single user. My model has several users and my aim is to get the difference between these two times and store the difference within the same model but I am not so sure how to do it.

**models.py:**

```
class Gettime(models.Model):
    id= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    stop_time = models.DateTimeField()
    hours = models.IntegerField() #or is there a better data type to store the time difference?
```

**views.py:**

```
def diff(request):
    data = User.objects.filter(pk__gt=1) 
    time_table = []
    for user in data:
        start = Gettime.objects.filter(id = user).only('start_time')
        stop = Gettime.objects.filter(id = user).only('stop_time')
        diff = start - stop    #However, this doesn't work.
```

How can I get the time difference between the start_time and stop_time fields and store it within my model?

Comment: You are trying to get the time data from a **`QuerySet`** which is a list-like object. You need to iterate the QuerySet again

Comment: Apart from that, assigning an FK relation to the field **`id`** wouldn't be a nice idea

Comment: @foo-bar can you please show a small example please? I am new to Django.

Comment: @foo-bar why not add 'id' though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) is a good field to store the diff between two `DateTimeFields`

```
diff = models.DurationField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Then you can update every instance of this field in the whole table with just one query

```
from django.db.models import F
Gettime.objects.update(diff=F('stop_time') - F('end_time'))
```

`F` is a [query expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions), it is way of referencing existing fields/values in the database/query. For instance you can use an `F` expression to increment a field in an update `Model.objects.update(int_field=F('int_field') + 1)`

After you have done this you should add a signal handler to the `Gettime` model that sets the value of `diff` on every save

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Gettime)
def my_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.diff = instance.stop_time - instance.start_time
```

This will make sue that `diff` is always set on the model

Comment: what does F stand for?

Comment: It's not good to use a ***DurationField*** field **here** since it won't automatically get updated during the changes.

Comment: It's good to ***generate the `third value`*** by using any of the **two** fields

Comment: @foo-bar how about just generate the time and save it in the model using DurationField?

Comment: @Iain what does **Model.objects.update(int_field=F('int_field') + 1)** mean?

Comment: @danny_boy it means "update every row in the Model table and add 1 to the int_field column"

Comment: Added another bit of info regarding signals

Comment: @foo-bar I'm not sire why you think a DurationField is not a good choice for this?

Comment: @IainShelvington just give me some time buddy, my system crashed, I will notify you if it works :) Thank you so much for suggesting this though